# Closing a socket

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

I have a socket and four streams created out of it:

- `InputStream`
- `OutputStream`
- `ObjectInputStream`
- `ObjectOutputStream`

What do I need to do to close all the streams along with the socket? I thought closing the socket would be enough, but I've been getting `EOFExceptions`...

The less code, the better.

More about the problem:

I open a connection and send UTF String trought object stream. It's contents start diferenet protocols on the server. When protocol is executed, server waits for a new UTF String.

At one point, clients executes:

```
objectOutputStream.writeUTF("terminate");
objectOutputStream.flush(); //Is this even necessary?
socket.close();
```

At the server end, something like this happens:

```
String command = objectInputStream.readUTF();
if (command.equals("terminate")
{
    socket.close();
}

//socket is not accessed after this point, until a new conenction is established
//(when socket and everything is reinitialized)
```

Comment: What did you expect after closing the socket other than exceptions?

Comment: When you close the socket, you're closing the streams of/from those sockets as well. If you try to do operations on closed streams (of closed sockets) you are supposed to get an exception and/or EOF.

Comment: You can skip the `.flush()` if you wrap it with a `BufferedOutputStream `. And since your are using the `Decorator` pattern for your streams you can close the outermost.

Answer (score 3):

Use a try-with-resources block and this will all be handled for you:

```
try (InputStream is = new InputStream(socket);
    OutputStream os = new OutputStream(socket);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is)
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(os)) {
   // Do stuff here
}
```

All your streams (and anything else that implements `AutoCloseable` will automatically be closed for you as you exit the try block.

To close the underlying streams when you close the holding stream it closes the lower ones too (i.e. closing the `ois` will also close the `is`) but it does no harm to keep them all in the try-with-resources block.

Comment: So should I close both object streams AND the socket itself? Or just object streams?

Comment: If in doubt close them all (Socket is `AutoCloseable` too). The real question though is why you were still trying to read from/write to the stream after closing the socket...because that's not going to work :)

Answer (score 2):

1. You only need to close the outermost output stream or Writer that you've wrapped around the socket output stream. That ensures it gets flushed.
2. Closing any of the streams or the socket closes the others.
3. EOFException is *normal.* It means you've reached the end of the stream.

Comment: So EOFException is thrown every time the socket is closed? Not when trying to read from closed socket/stream?

Comment: No. EOFException is thrown when you call readXXX() for any X other than readLine() which returns null; read() returns -1. And when the *peer* has closed the connection, not when *you* have closed the *socket.*